# My soundless Android app keeps interrupting the Audio focus of other apps on forground

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, audio

My android application that has no sound keeps interrupting the [Audio focus](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioFocusRequest) of other apps running in the background such as Spotify and Youtube Music, every time the apps become visible (forground). Which then causes the sound or video running in the background to pause.

The app is made using Unity. I have tried to grab the Audio Focus myself onResume(), then release it:

```
AudioManager am = (AudioManager) currentActivity.getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
int res = am.requestAudioFocus(null, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN_TRANSIENT);
if (res == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_REQUEST_GRANTED)
   am.abandonAudioFocus(null);
```

This works, however not consistently. With Youtube Music for example, doesn't work at all.

I am looking for a way to tell the OS, "Do not interrupt the audio focus of other apps at all"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the option at build settings in unity "Mute other Audio Sources" is what's causing this issues if it was set to true. This was poorly documented as I though it is for the in app audios only. The reason I check this option is because unity 2018 combined with target android SDK 31 and above will cause issues if this option wasn't checked.